# Error building LAPACK on Redhat 4.1

Tags: installation, lapack, atlas

I am trying to build LAPACK (the full version) with ATLAS on Redhat 4.1. I have been successful in building ATLAS depending upon the tarfile of lapack:

atlas/configure --prefix=HOME/atlas --with-netlib-lapack-tarfile=HOME/lapack-3.4.1.tgz
make build
make check
make install

But I need the whole installation of LAPACK. I found

http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/atlas_install/atlas_install.html

and

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.136.5309%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=3C8YUKaqOIqm8AT6kYC4Cg&usg=AFQjCNHKbHg1H0qupmzQbj9tGq3tsmXRDQ&sig2=etIB36nxjasjUg4sEwQ0DQ

which suggest changing a few lines of the default make.inc.example to build the rest of LAPACK. However, I am unsuccessful in getting even the default build of LAPACK to work:

```
cp make.inc.example make.inc
compute-1-29.local make
( cd INSTALL; make; ./testlsame; ./testslamch; ./testdlamch; \
./testsecond; ./testdsecnd; ./testieee; ./testversion )
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jmorgens/lap/lapack/INSTALL'
gfortran  -O0 -c slamch.f -o slamch.o
/share/apps/gcc-trunk/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.2.0/f951: error    while loading shared libraries: libmpfr.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [slamch.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jmorgens/lap/lapack/INSTALL'
 ASCII character set
Tests completed
/bin/sh: ./testslamch: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: ./testdlamch: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: ./testsecond: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: ./testdsecnd: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: ./testieee: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: ./testversion: No such file or directory
make: *** [lapack_install] Error 127
```

Suggestions?